# How many 4 digit numbers without $0$ between $1000$ and $9999$ are divisible by $3$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Determine the number of numbers we can make between $1000$ and $9999$
>   of $4$ different digits without $0$. How many of those numbers are
>   divisible by $3$?

To calculate how many numbers there are between $1000$ and $9999$ of $4$ different digits without $0$
, we calculate $9*8*7*6=3024$.

To calculate how many of those numbers are divisible by $3$ , I tried to combine that the sum of the digits must be divisible by $3$ and the stars and bars theorem.

Since we have 4 different digits the maximum sum of the digits is $9+8+7+6=30$ and the minimum is $1+2+3+4=10$.

The possible sums of the digits for which the number is divisible by $3$ are thus $12,15,18,21,24,27$ and $30$.

But with the stars and bars I didn't really know how to do its because we have to have 4 different digits and no zeros.

The solution my book gave was simply $42*4!$, so I think I'm on the wrong track, but  I have no idea how they got to their solution.

Any nudge in the right direction is appreciated :)

**EDIT**

I figured out the solution from my book.

If we take the numbers 1 to 9 we can divide them in 3 sets mod 3.
0 mod 3  would be the numbers {3,6,9}

1 mod 3 would be the numbers {1,4,7}

2 mod 3 would be the numbers {2,5,8}

Now we can use that the sum of the 4 digits must be $0$.

We can take 1 number from the 0 mod 3 set and 3 from the 1 mod 3 set, for example 3147. There are 4! ways to use the numbers {3,4,1,7}. There are 3 ways to select 1 number from 0 mod 3 set and 3 from the 1 mod 3 set.

Other ways to get a sum of 3:

2 numbers from the 0 mod 3 + 1 number from 2 mod 3+ 1 number from 1 mod 3. There are 3*3*3=27 ways to do this.

3 numbers from 2 mod 3+1 from  0 mod 3 . There are 3 ways to do this.

2 numbers from 1 mod 3 + 2 numbers from 2 mod 3. There are 3*3= 9 ways to do this.

So there are  3+27+3+9=42 ways to get a 4 digit number with sum equal to 3, and we have 4! ways to rearrange those numbers, so 42*4! numbers between 1000 and 9999  comply with all the requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $3024$ such numbers in total, as as you say. And exactly one third of these numbers is divisible by $3$.

We can see this by grouping them into three sets $S_0,S_1,$ and $S_2$, according to the sum of their digits modulo $3$. Given any element of $S_0$, we can construct a unique element of $S_1$ simply by adding $1$ to each digit (with $9$ wrapping around to $1$). And we can construct a unique element of $S_2$ in the same way by adding $2$ to each digit.

So these three sets are all the same size, which is $3024/3=1008$.